# Make Amcharts slice take the whole pie chart

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to trying to remove a small gap when I have a pie chart with a 100% slice.

I've tried to give it a outlineThickness of 0 but there is still a very small gap.

[Here is an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/bcamarneiro/s083cdpk/)

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 10
  }],
  "outlineThickness": 0,
  "outlineAlpha": 1,
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This options should be used:

```
"outlineThickness": 1,
"outlineAlpha": 1,
"outlineColor": undefined
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bcamarneiro/wgcfta9h/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to work around this in current version is to apply the same color to outline as the slice itself. You can use [`outlineColor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#outlineColor) for that:

https://jsfiddle.net/s083cdpk/1/

Please note that this should be applies only if there's only one slice, as the same color will be applied to all slices if there are more.

Comment: That's what I thought. Although it's a possible workaround, it is not exactly what I was looking for..